# Call native .NET interfaces from Python in a client-server architecture

Tags: python, c#, .net, unity-game-engine, client-server

There is a game called Kerbal Space Program (KSP), written using the Unity game engine in C#. It has rich modding scene. Some mods add new features and game object types with new APIs.

There is one mod, called [kRPC](https://github.com/krpc/krpc), which allows for remote procedure calls of Kerbal's and its mods' APIs in various languages, including Python, through a client-server architecture - the running Kerbal game being the server. The mod works, but has some drawbacks:

- it has stalled development which stopped at KSP v 1.5.1 (at least that's the version I was able to make working with my code)
- it requires writing definition and a small amout of wrapper code of each of the Kerbal's or its mods' methods to be able to call them from the client

I suspect/assume the second drawback is also the main reason why the development has stalled and covers only a handful of the game's functionality, as with each breaking update or a new mod, the definitions and wrappers need to be fixed and/or extended.

I am mainly interested in the Python language interface kRPC provides. I was wondering if there was a better way to achieve similar functionality, but without the need to re-define all the game's interfaces anew. What I would like to achieve:

- keep client-server architecture, but make it very thin and lightweight
- write a code in Python that queries or changes the state of the game using its native interfaces
- execute said code in the game and return the results in case of a query
- if the result is a reference to an object, reuse that reference for a subsequent call (e.g. call 1 queries the spaceship object on the launchpad and returns a reference to it, code 2 references the spaceship and starts its engine when a condition is met within the context of the client)

What solution would you design for such functionality and what technologies (and how) would you use?

Would you think of a completely different solution to remove the second drawback of the kRPC mod?

After doing some searching, I've found [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet), which seems it would solve the direct calling of the native game interfaces from within Python. I am not sure how to make the client-server part working seamlessly with .NET technologies.

Answer (score 0):

The point of RPC is to disconnect the structure of your Python client from the KSP 'server'.  `Python.Net` does not suit your purpose; it's not for connecting python to a running .Net application, it's about loading .Net dlls into a Python process as if they were Python packages.

Because RPC provides that architectural disconnect, it means you have to code the Server-side and the Client-side APIs separately (and work out how they talk to each other).

The best way for you to achieve your goals is to fork kRPC and add/fix what you need.

Alternatively, look into kOS.

Comment: Python is a must-have.

Comment: Forking kRPC does not achive my goals as it retains the second drawback.